# Can't get parameters to work with OdbcConnection in C#

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, intersystems-cache

I'm running a query with a couple date constraints.  If I execute the code below with the dates hardcoded and no parameters, I get a result I expect (a simple integer).  However, when I try to use parameters I get an empty result set.  No errors, just no results.

```
log("Connecting to SQL Server...");
string connectionString = "DSN=HSBUSTEST32;";

string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE myDateTime >= '?' AND myDateTime < '?'";
//string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE myDateTime >= '@startDate' AND myDateTime < '@endDate'";

string startDate = "2016-08-23";
string endDate = "2016-08-24";

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("startDate",startDate);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("endDate", endDate);
    //command.Parameters.Add("startDate", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "2016-08-23";
    //command.Parameters.Add("endDate", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "2016-08-24";

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            log(reader[0].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've tried both named parameters as well as using the `?` placeholder.  I've also tried a couple different methods of adding the parameters, `Add()` and `AddWithValue()`, though truthfully I don't understand the difference.

What is causing the empty results?

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes from your query? Also i would advice to addr the datatype to te Parameter.

Comment: ... removing the single quote fixed it.  Please explain. Is it implied in a parameter? /frustrated

Comment: does it only do that because the datatype is string?

Comment: Varchar might work, but I would think you would want to try using a different ODBCtype . .....Parameters.Add("startdate", OdbcType.Timestamp).Value= ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query like i said before is the single quote. If you pass in the value without a parameter you need to use those single quotes because this defines a string in a statement.

With the parameters the framework handels all this stuff for you. It also checks for sql injection and removes dissalowed chars. Especially for string and datetime values this is really helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working on the datatype but right now I'm getting `Failed to convert parameter value from a DateTime to a Byte[].` when I use `OdbcDatatype.Timestamp`.  I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: This error is because Timestamp represenrs a byte[] value. Maybe the type that fits to your need would be Datetime. In this [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbctype(v=vs.110).aspx) you see a list of all datatypes and the represented data.

Comment: With `DateTime` I get blank results again. Is there a way to see the "rendered" queryString in the debugger?  Even after `command.ExecuteReader()` it still has the `?` placeholders.

Comment: Can you add the currently used solution to your starting post?

Comment: No, but I posted a followup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174830/parameterized-odbc-query-works-with-varchar-but-not-datetime

Answer (score -1):

Keep using this:

```
string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE myDateTime >= @startDate AND myDateTime < @endDate";
```

but try this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate",startDate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate);
```