# Parameterized ODBC Query works with VarChar but not DateTime?

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

As followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174553/cant-get-parameters-to-work-with-odbcconnection-in-c-sharp), everything was working when I was manually defining the dates like `2016-05-01` as strings/varchars.  However, when I went to convert to datetime I'm now getting empty results again. This is the code as it stands:

```
log("Connecting to SQL Server...");
string connectionString = "DSN=HSBUSTEST32;";

// Provide the query string with a parameter placeholder.
string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE myDateTime >= ? AND myDateTime < ?";

// Specify the parameter value.
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddHours(-1);

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
    OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@startDate", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
    command.Parameters.Add("@endDate", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = endDate;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            log(reader[0].ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Again, if I were to replace the following:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddHours(-1);
```

with

```
string startDate = "2016-08-23";
string endDate = "2016-08-24";
```

And then change the `OdbcType` to `VarChar` everything works fine.

Comment: What's the datatype of `myDateTime1`? and again you should be using `executescalar()` instead

Comment: `myDateTime` is an [tag:intersystems-cache] `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is with the date range.

```
// Specify the parameter value.
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddHours(-1);
```

endDate will be 1 hour less than start date.  The comparison operator in your query is greater than first parameter and less than second parameter.

For example:

```
string queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE myDateTime >= '8/26/2016 14:30:00' AND myDateTime < '8/26/2016 13:30:00'";
```

No date exists that's greater than 2:30pm and less than 1:30pm of the same date. :)

Maybe you meant

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddHours(1);
```

Comment: and obviously since I can't run a query on the future I changed `endDate` to `DateTime.Now` and `startDate` to `.addHours(-1)`

Comment: It's really easy to do when you're using positional parameters.  Named parameters will at least prevent the case where you add the endDate before the startDate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your dateformat. What you are passing at the moment is a date with a time, but you wanna have only the date. You should be good to go if you use the Datepart only from the Datetime.

You could do this either with a string format like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Or by using the date property:

```
DateTime.Now.Date;
```